# How do I get my program to write all the data it generates to a Text file I'm trying to a sentimental analysis of Twitter feeds?

Tags: python, twitter, io, text-files, bigdata

Ok, so I'm trying to do a sentimental analysis of twitter tweets and all my code works perfect to get a response of live tweets. However the shell deletes all the tweets after a certain amount was reached. I have been messing around with my code to try and write all the tweets to a text file but for the last 5 hours of my struggles I can not figure it out. Where the comment symbol # is code I added to try and write the information to my text file. I'm fairly new to python so if someone can help me out I would very much appreciate it.

I would use Git because I know how to write all the data to a text file in that program but I can't figure out how to get it to run my python files.

```
def twitterreq(url, method, parameters):
  req = oauth.Request.from_consumer_and_token(oauth_consumer,
                                         token=oauth_token,
                                         http_method=http_method,
                                         http_url=url, 
                                         parameters=parameters)

  req.sign_request(signature_method_hmac_sha1, oauth_consumer, oauth_token)

  headers = req.to_header()

  if http_method == "POST":
    encoded_post_data = req.to_postdata()
  else:
    encoded_post_data = None
    url = req.to_url()

  opener = urllib.OpenerDirector()
  opener.add_handler(http_handler)
  opener.add_handler(https_handler)

  response = opener.open(url, encoded_post_data)

  return response

def fetchsamples():
  url = "https://stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/sample.json"
  parameters = []
  response = twitterreq(url, "GET", parameters)
  f=open("C:\\Users\\name\\Desktop\\datasci_course_materials\\assignment1", "w") # my attempt
  for line in response:
    f.write(str(line) + "\n") # 100% sure im not using this command properly
    print line.strip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  fetchsamples()
```

I have left out the top of my code because we shouldn't need my access and consumer keys to answer this question. This code is in Python 2.7

Comment: What do you mean when you say the shell is deleting the tweets? Does the script end and then you restart the script and the original tweets are gone?

Comment: I have to let it run for 10 mins to capture enough Big Data to do some analysis on it which python starts to delete after a certain point while its running. So I need to capture all the data for around 10mins to do analysis on it. Yes the shell deletes it before I restart but it keeps about the last 30sec to 1 min of tweets

Answer (score 0):

Could try something along the lines of.

```
try:
    with open("filename.txt", "a") as f:
        for n in response:
            f.write(n + "\n")
        f.close()
except IOError as e:
    print e
except TypeError as t:
    print t
```

This will attempt to open filename.txt and append each item in "response" to a new line. It will capture IO errors and Type errors.

Comment: It spits this error out when I try implementing the code you suggested and before I tried it to it was the same error.

Comment: File "C:\Users\jake\Desktop\datasci_course_materials\assignment1\twitterstream.py", line 73, in <module>
    fetchsamples()
  File "C:\Users\jake\Desktop\datasci_course_materials\assignment1\twitterstream.py", line 58, in fetchsamples
    f=open("C:\\Users\\jake\\Desktop\\datasci_course_materials\\assignment1", "w")
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\jake\\Desktop\\datasci_course_materials\\assignment1'

Comment: The traceback says that `assignment1` is a folder instead of it being a file like you implied with your code, add a filename to the end of it. You're trying to use a folder as a file which won't work, and that's what the error says.

Answer (score 0):

The line `f=open("<filename>", "w") # my attempt` means that if it stops, your file will just be lost completely and erased. Every time that your program runs this line it erases the file and then opens it.

Try changing the mode `"a"`, which means that each subsequent call will just add data to the end.

```
f = open("<filename>", "a") # Appending instead of overwriting.
```

Extra information: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open